# Reading textfile in R

Tags: r

I have a text file which is tab delimited, Sample data of the file is like

```
Id<\t> Address<\t> City <br>
1<\t>  ABC<\t>   Brookyln<br>
2<\t> DHF<\t>    Philadelphia<br>
```

I used

```
data <- read.table(file.choose(), sep="\t",quote = "",header=TRUE)
```

function to read that text file.

But when I am trying to access the first column, it is giving as null

```
data$Id
NULL
```

But when i tried accessing other columns it worked

```
data$City
Brooklyn
Philadelphia
```

I also tried reading that as a data frame

```
data <- as.data.frame(read.table(file.choose(), sep="\t",quote = "",header=TRUE))
```

But still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"NULL" is the output R returns when you try to read an non-existing column. So it seems that the Id column does not exists.

To see the names of the columns that exist in your data run the colnames(data) to make sure your Id column exists.

Comment: When i ran that, it came as<br> "ï..Id"  "Address"  "City"

Comment: Right. You can do colnames(data)[1] <- "Id" . That will rename your first column to Id. Then running data$Id should return your values.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Do you have any idea why the first column name got changed automatically in the first place?

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer was helpful, you can accept it as a solution by clicking on the check icon on the left. Regarding why the name got changed - could be many things (encoding when saving the data, or because the software used to save adds special characters at the beginning, etc.). I can't say for sure ;)